# How to fetch a record containing something if Count(*)=0

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a set of tables containing staff memebers' secondary specialities in different formats. Actually, only few primary specialities allow a person to have a secondary speciality.

I make a UNION view, combining the secondary specialities in this way and it is working fine:

```
SELECT tpl.id, tpl.speciality, 20 as gr FROM tpath_list tpl
UNION ALL
SELECT tlt.id, tlt.lab_type as speciality, 11 as gr FROM tlab_types tlt
UNION ALL
SELECT til.id, til.speciality, 10 as gr FROM tinstrumental_list til
```

Field `gr` contains the index field of the primary specialities (10, 11 and 20) allowing to have a secondary speciality. All other specialities (with id 1, 2, 3 etc.) do not have secondary ones.

I receive something like this...

[image]

I can now fetch data from the created view using `WHERE gr=:n`.

How can I modify the view so that fetching data from it using `WHERE gr=:n` (1, 2, 3 etc.) clause will give me a single record `id=1 speciality="Not specified" gr=n`

**Appended on comments of the community:**

I need to fetch all the records if `:n IN(10,11,20)` that are present in the tables and presented by the view. For example, 3 records listed in the picture for `:n=20`. Only if `:n NOT IN(10,11,20)` I need an additional (single) record absenting from the tables (and the view). Please, note that records with `gr IN(10,11,20)` have got the `id=1` and `speciality='Not specified'`.

**Appended on request of  Jon Tofte-Hansen**

Here is an unfiltered view output (without `WHERE` clause).

[image]

If I fetch the view with `WHERE gr=20` I get the following (that is what I want):

[image]

If with `WHERE gr=10` - this set (that is what I want):

[image]

If I fetch it with `WHERE gr=1` then I woud like to receive a sigle record that is absent in any of the tables used for view creation. I wish to get this output but do not know how to:

[image]

Here is the structure of the tables if it might help:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tspecialities_list`;
CREATE TABLE `tspecialities_list` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `speciality` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`speciality`),
  KEY `i_by_speciality` (`speciality`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tlab_types`;
CREATE TABLE `tlab_types` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lab_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tpath_list`;
CREATE TABLE `tpath_list` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `speciality` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`speciality`),
  KEY `i_by_speciality` (`speciality`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tinstrumental_list`;
CREATE TABLE `tinstrumental_list` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `speciality` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`speciality`),
  KEY `i_by_speciality` (`speciality`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: You probably need an aggregate function. But first, let's clarify. If you select WHERE gr=20, then which of the three records will be that one single record we want? We need additional criteria for selection.

Comment: @dimm Thank you for your attention. If I Select WHERE gr=20 I need to get the dataset, containing 3 records listed in the picture. Only for the other gr values (except 10, 11 and 20) I need to fetch a single record absenting from the given view.

Comment: Can you please show sample data, what you get and what you expect. It is not very clear what you want.

Comment: You need to show the table with the primary specialities, and the full view text not only the unions of the detail tables.

Comment: @JonTofte-Hansen Please, kindly have a look at the appended question

Comment: @JonTofte-Hansen I have added the structure of tables, if it can help you

Comment: the problem with the new update is that it is not true.  that row -- the "not specified" is returned with every other request.  We see it in the 3 other valid queries.  So what exactly is this view supposed to show... `id` columns that don't exist anywhere else?  That would make sense but where is the table that contains those id values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you want, but this could be it. Add an extra union that produce all the id's not present in the three tables with secondary specialities:

```
 SELECT tpl.id, tpl.speciality, 20 as gr FROM tpath_list tpl
UNION ALL
SELECT tlt.id, tlt.lab_type as speciality, 11 as gr FROM tlab_types tlt
UNION ALL
SELECT til.id, til.speciality, 10 as gr FROM tinstrumental_list til

UNION ALL
select tsl.id, 'Not specified', tsl.id as gr from tspecialities_list tsl
 where tsl.id not in
 (SELECT tpl.id FROM tpath_list tpl
  UNION
  SELECT tlt.id FROM tlab_types tlt
  UNION
  SELECT til.id FROM tinstrumental_list til)
```

Comment: I used your idea and added the last `UNION ALL` instead: `SELECT 1 AS `id`,'Not specified' AS `speciality`,`tsl`.`id` AS `gr` from `tspecialities_list` `tsl` where (`tsl`.`id` not in (10,11,20))` This gave me the result I was expecting.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you are just asking for the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM viewname
WHERE speciality='Not specified' and gr=:n
```

Is there a reason this isn't what you want?

Comment: Thank you, Hogan. No. It is not, unfortunately. I need to get a dataset containing more records if gr in(10,11,20). Only for the other values I need a record absenting from the view. Please, see my comment for the question

Comment: hmm... this would be easy with a CTE but I don't know the best way to do it in mysql.

Comment: Then may I ask you to delete your answer? I suppose that zero answer score might attract the community attention.

Comment: You can ask but I won't do it.